# Questions about Drombler FX for NetBeans Platform RCP application

Tags: netbeans-platform, drombler-fx

I am looking for a JavaFX application framework to use in a NetBeans Platform based application. Would it be possible to use Drombler FX in it? I looked at other alternatives (mFx and eFX, but seem abandoned) and I would like to avoid the mixed look of Swing with JavaFX.

I tried to run the sample application to get a better idea of its functionality, but I got an error when I follow the get started instructions to generate it:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.drombler.fx:drombler-fx-maven-archetype-application:0.8-SNAPSHOT)
```

Lastly, is Drombler FX under active development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the main developer of Drombler FX.

> Lastly, is Drombler FX under active development?

Yes, Drombler FX is under active development.

> The desired archetype does
>   not exist
>   (org.drombler.fx:drombler-fx-maven-archetype-application:0.8-SNAPSHOT)

Please note, that at the time of writing, the latest released version is 0.7.
All artifacts of v0.7 have been deployed to Maven Central and should be available.
You can find the Getting Started page of the v0.7 tutorial [here](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted).

If you really want to use the SNAPSHOT versions of the current development, please add a proxy to the following repo to your Maven Repository Manager (such as Nexus):

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

> I am looking for a JavaFX application framework to use in a NetBeans
>   Platform based application. Would it be possible to use Drombler-FX in
>   it? I looked at other alternatives (mFx and eFX, but seem abandoned)
>   and I would like to avoid the mixed look of Swing with JavaFX.

Drombler FX has not been designed for integration in a NetBeans Platform Application and it does not support NetBeans Platform Modules out-of-the-box. As the NetBeans Platform supports OSGi (at least to some degree?), I guess you would have to find replacements at least for the bootstraping code, which you can find here:

- https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-acp/tree/develop/drombler-acp-startup-main
- https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/tree/develop/drombler-fx-startup-main

But even if you would manage it, wouldn't you still have the mix of Swing and JavaFX you would like to avoid?